# Android Program design

Tags: android, multithreading, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm fairly new to Android development so I was wondering how I should design/structure a new program I want to develop. I'm not sure if it should be started as a service or a broadcast receiver or an activity even (all I have ever done).

What I want to do is receive when certain events happen on the phone such as when the following are turned on blue-tooth, wifi, gps and camera. And when that happens send a message to a network manager (using SNMP).

Now I want this to continually run in the background waiting for these events to happen.  Do I create a service and create receivers to create receivers and when the action happens create a service/tread to act on it/generate the SNMP message?

When that Is answered I was also struggling with how the manifest file would be structured fro when running receivers and services within the same set of code. But I guess that depends on how you design it to run?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a broadcast receiver which gets notified about the listed events and start a server who asynchronously send some messages.

Comment: I tried this simple example of a broadcast receiver and it seems to just run and then end. http://code.google.com/p/carbot/source/browse/trunk/src/net/cardroid/BluetoothBroadcastReceiver.java?r=8 So a little confused maybe don't have the manifest.XML right as not sure what the action value should be for the receiver.

Comment: I have a simple broadcastReceiver working but having an issue sending an SNMP trap.  I believe it's a permissions problem as I don't want to restrict any broadcaster from sending certain events thus did not list permissions but to send a SNMP trap I certainly need to so I think to do this I need to spawn a service to do that work?